# Replacing Dimmable Halogen Spot light with LED dimmable or non Dimmable LED spotlights

Tags: led, dimmer-switch, bulb, halogen, transformer

I have old fashion dimmable halogen spotlight mounted on my ceiling, and I would like to replace them with LED spot lights.

My questions are:

- Would I have to replace the existing transformers to use dimmable LED spotlights?
- If so, would I also have to replace the existing transformers if I chose instead to use non-dimmable LED spotlights?

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced low voltage halogens with LED equivalent and had no issues with dimming.  But, this is not always the case.  I've had to take back a whole case because they had interference with radio signals.

Call the manufacturer and ask them.  That's what we all do when we don't know.

Comment: Or just buy one of each different type you can find and try it out. Return the ones that don't work. If non work, get a new dimmer and try again.